# Normalizing to zero mean and unit variance before regression

Tags: regression, normalization, vector-autoregression

I'm new to regression (vector autoregression), and recently encountered the following issue:

1. If I use raw dependent and independent variables to do the regression, the $R^2$, DW-d test and standard error of estimate for each dependent variable are quite good. The $R^2$ is above $95\%$.
2. However, When the dependent and independent variables are normalized to zero mean and unit variables (column normalized), these measures got worse. The $R^2$ ranges from $60\%-90\%$.

So what happened after I normalized the data?

Comment: I don't think it is possible for the $R^2$ to change.  You didn't state the reason for normalization.  I can't think of any.

Answer (score 1):

Frank Harrell is right, it's not possible for the R<sup>2</sup> to change, ***unless*** you've done something unusual like ... removed the intercept from your regression.  See for yourself with this [R-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=vZQXGkIb&version=1).

My suggestion?  Put the intercept back in.  See, for example, *"[Regression through the Origin and Its Pitfalls](http://courses.washington.edu/qsci483/Lectures/20.pdf)"*.